# Submitting a Form using PHP and AJAX via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So I am using "load" functions of jQuery to use ajax on my pages.

Can anyone write a small snippet of code using jquery load (or any ajax function which you think is the best) ? What I do is make a form, onsubmit pass to js, further using GET pass values into the load function and return false; though this works I am sure this is not the best way. Also this does NOT work in Opera.

Comment: Please give us some more information, maybe some code snippets that you wrote, so we have something to work off of.

Comment: I gave info on what I did but I don't think it was the right way, like using cellotape to stick a house together. So I needed a better solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is submit a form to an existing server-side script using AJAX.  If so, consider using the [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).  It will let you very easily make an existing form submit via AJAX.

If that's not your goal, we'll need a lot more detail about what — specifically — you're trying to accomplish.